# Class providing iterator for contents

Tags: python, iterator

There is plenty of documentation on how a Python class can implement the iterator protocol from scratch, by providing the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.

But supposing each object will just contain a list, called e.g. `contents`, and the intent is that trying to iterate over the object, should just end up iterating over the `contents` list. It feels like there should be a simpler way to provide this.

What is the simple/idiomatic way for a class to provide iteration over a list of contents?

Comment: Not sure I fully get what your problem is, but isn't it basic inheritance + base class scenario?

Comment: Implementing the iterator protocol from scratch is usually **wrong** - in most cases, including yours, the object should be **iterable**, but not an **iterator**.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Exactly! So what's the syntax to do that?

Comment: @Vicrobot Well sure, that would be a way to solve the problem. But I feel there must be a more elegant, idiomatic way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.contents)
```

Implementing the iterator protocol is the wrong way to provide iteration support. If you want to provide iteration support, you need an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator. In most cases, your object should not itself be an iterator, and your object should not have a `__next__` method.

Comment: @Vicrobot: Those words in that order don't form an intelligible question. I can't tell what you're trying to say.

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous. As you're advising not to make object iterator itself, are there any loss behind that?

Comment: @Vicrobot: Making the object its own iterator prevents you from having two iterators, so nested loops or concurrent access don't work, for example.

Comment: @tdelaney: No, defining `__iter__` makes an object an *iterable*, not an *iterator*.

Comment: @tdelaney: See the [data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), where the iterator protocol is clearly defined as containing both a self-returning `__iter__` method and `__next__`.

Answer (score 1):

Just return an iterator for the member variable you want iterate.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, some_sequence):
        self.contents = list(some_sequence)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.contents)
```

In this example I turned the initial sequence into a list so that multiple iterations of the object go through the list again. If you don't do `list` then you get whatever iteration the original sequence likes (a file object or iterator would only go through the sequence once).